# Why does views::split ignore an empty sub-range after a delimiter if it's the last element of the input range?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

For the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/63hPM1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = " text ";
    auto sv = std::ranges::views::split(s, ' ');                    
    std::cout << std::ranges::distance(sv.begin(), sv.end());
}
```

the output is 2. The empty sub-range after the last delimiter is not present in the output range.

This seems inconsistent, since I expect there to be `N+1` sub-ranges in the output range if there are `N` occurrences of the delimiter in the input range. Why is this not the case?

Note that range-v3 does exactly the [same](https://godbolt.org/z/f4doh6) thing, so I'm sure this is intentional, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that split will take all characters _up until_ the delimiter.  So, since you have a delimiter at the beginning of the string, you will get all characters that come before it (in this case, no characters).

Comment: From what I understand from [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.split#outer-6), it seems expected :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but doesn't that seem odd? I'm trying to write some code, and stumbled upon this (inconsistency?), and having to work around this is unpleasant.

Comment: @cigien: It probably makes a lot more sense when you're splitting ranges of arbitrary objects, rather than processing string ranges.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not sure what you mean. What's the difference when splitting arbitrary ranges? Is the behavior different?

Comment: How would you implement iterator of that view and more particularly `end()`? Handling this special case seems to require extra space/treatment. As I saw, there is already special case for empty separator, where each character is a sub-range (and we don't have empty subrange at start or end).

Comment: Submitted [LWG 3478](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3478). This just seems obviously wrong to me.

Comment: @Barry Oh, very nice, thanks. Yeah, seems wrong, or at least weirdly inconsistent. I didn't think of comparing to other languages, that's a good point.

Comment: Now, gcc (truck) already contains a fix and prints 3: https://godbolt.org/z/vTGsdo91q

Comment: @Fedor Thanks again :) I should probably, at some point, go through my own questions about compiler variance, and see which, if any, have been resolved.

Comment: What do we think should happen with an empty string here, versus that Issue? Will we get an empty set of ranges back, as I currently do - or should we get a set of one empty string?